Text segmenting, line segmentation, from line to words, from words to characters with Python & OpenCV
For a text image input, I need to break the text into segments using the OPENCV library
Let's say the image has 4 lines of text, I need to write a function that breaks down and cuts the lines and creates 4 new images for each line respectively.
Then a function that receives a line/sentence that consists of several words and cuts images of the words separately.
Then a function that receives an image of a word and decomposes it into letters, for each letter its own image will be created.
The function below cutting only one word to letters
# Cutting one word to letters
def image_to_text(image_file_path):
        img = cv2.imread(image_file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        extracted_text = ""

        if img is not None:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            _, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
            contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            for idx, contour in enumerate(contours):
                x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                letter_img = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]], np.float32)
                letter_img = cv2.filter2D(letter_img, -1, kernel)
                letter_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(letter_img, 4, 4, 4, 4, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])
                letter_img = cv2.resize(letter_img, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

                # Display the image
                plt.imshow(letter_img, cmap='gray')
                plt.axis('off')
                plt.show()
                letter_img = letter_img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1).astype('float32') / 255

                prediction = loaded_model.predict(letter_img)
                # Print the predicted class and its corresponding label
                predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)
                predicted_label = class_labels[predicted_class]
                print(f"Predicted class for the letter: {predicted_class} ({predicted_label})")
                extracted_text += predicted_label
        extracted_text = extracted_text[::-1]
        print('Extracted text:', extracted_text)
        return extracted_text


text = image_to_text(r"C:\Users\student\Desktop\FinalProject\Flask\image\test3IMG.jpg")

input: 
output:
I am limited in the pictures I can upload to the forum, so I will only upload two examples of the letters B and E


The rest of the letters were extracted in the same way..

the question is how can i handle an input like this:

I'm trying for days and I'm getting frustrated.. will be glad for help

Why are you doing your Laplacian sharpening filter at each letter rather than doing once for the whole image? It would be faster this way. Why do you use pet.imshow rather than cv2.imshow?

Because I'm new to this field.

hope this helps.
To find each line:

Threshold the image with
Close the image with custom kernel that only connects vertical blobs (xAxisKernel() is the custom function i wrote to create the kernel that has 1 in its center and neighbouring rows, 0 elswhere )
Find external contours which will be the contours of each line

This is the thresholded image:

This is the closed image with 17 kernel size, now all lines are connected as one big blob:

This is the bounding boxes for each contour which are all detected lines:

Now repeating the same procedure for detecting each word in one line:

Cut the line portion of image
Threshold the cut portion (or just cut the thresholded verison)
Close the image with custom kernel that only connects vertical blobs
Find external contours which will be the contours of each word

This the thresholded line image:

This is the closed image with 7 kernel size, smaller kernel because we just want to connect the letters of a word instead of connecting each word together:

This is the bounding boxes for each contour which are all detected lines:

This is the final result of word detection:

From this point you can use your own code that detects each letter of a word for every detected word.
This is the complete code:
import cv2
import numpy

#Funciton to create custom kernel
def xAxisKernel(size):
    size = size if size%2 else size+1
    xkernel = numpy.zeros((size,size),dtype=numpy.uint8)
    center = size//2
    for j in range(size):
        xkernel[center][j] = 1
        xkernel[center-1][j] = 1
        xkernel[center+1][j] = 1
    return xkernel

#Give filtered image, get bounding boxes for the lines
def findLines(full_image):

    #Threshold the image, close with custom kernel to connect only vertical blobs which are letters
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(full_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,xAxisKernel(17)) #Connecting every word of a line together
    
    #Find line contours in the closed image
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    lines = []
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>100: #to eliminate the dots
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            lines.append([x,y,w,h])
    return lines


#Give the cropped image of a line, get bounding boxes for the words 
def findWords(line_image):

    #Add white border around the line for better filtering
    line_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(line_image,top=10,bottom=10,left=10,right=10,borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=[255, 255, 255])

    #Threshold the image, close with custom kernel to connect only vertical blobs which are letters
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(line_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,xAxisKernel(7)) #Connecting the letters of a word

    #Find word contours in the closed image
    contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    words = []
    for cnt in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(cnt)>100:#to eliminate the dots
            x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
            words.append([x-10,y-10,w,h]) #subtracting the added border size for correction
            cv2.rectangle(line_image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

    return words


#Read the image
image = cv2.imread('ph1.png')
height,width,channel = image.shape

# Find all lines in the image
al_lines = findLines(image)

# Iterate on each line and find all words
for line in al_lines:
    lineX,lineY,lineW,lineH = line #Line bounding box coordinates
    words = findWords(image[lineY:lineY+lineH,lineX:lineX+lineW])
    
    for word in words:
        x,y,w,h = word #Word bounding box coordinates
        
        # Add line start position as offset to word start position for correction
        x = x+lineX
        y = y+lineY
        #Draw bounding box around each word
        cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('Original',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

